# How do I get the location field to show anything in plone-4.x collections

Tags: collections, plone, plone-4.x

I am trying to use a collection that will list items by state and provide a link to them in the location field of a table listing.  The reason the location is important is that the same item can be added to lots of different folders/objects, so the title and type is not informative enough.  Anyway, my problem is that the location gives a blank entry in the table displaying the collection.  I have tried this for all types of items on my site: pages, folders, custom dexterity content types, etc..  Any hints?

Present configuration is Plone-4.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "location" field you are using is probably the ones only populated by the Event content type (please, check it).

If I'm not wrong, you can:

1. add a new index to the catalog that index the `getLocation` attribute, that will load the "Location" metadata; then add a new collection configuration for loading this new metadata
2. [add a new indexer](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/catalog-indexing-strategies.html#creating-custom-indexers) that will load the `getLocation` information using the same "location"

The 1 is the easy way (probably you can do all TTW) but way 2 is cleaner (but require some development)

Comment: You are correct about the "location" field in the search options being the "location" in events.  I haven't got any alternatives to work.  What I need is a way to display the "path" item which is indexed normally.  Usually I think it is used as the link for the title.  This is putting me on the right track.  Thanks.